# How to set paths for menu items in hierarchy to make it work with Superfish

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm confused about what to do with the menu items whose sole function is 'to be parent' i.e. no content attached to them. One way I wanted to solve this is to set the path to `<front>` for those items. But then subitems just won't fly out anymore.

Similarly, if I set the path of a parent item to the node that belongs to a child item, the parent just totally disappears out of the menu, leave alone that there would be a child to pop out of.

Comment: The menu in this context is the hierarchical structure representing the *content/pages* in your site. It doesn't really make sense that any menu item would not have a piece of content/page associated with it. If you find yourself in this position for whatever reason though, consider making the 'parent' page an introduction to the child pages under it.

Comment: To me it doens't make sense to have to assign content to each menu item either, especially in this context. The problem is that, whenever I want to add a menu item to my menu structure, a path is required. If I assign to the menu item a path to a node that isn't assigned to any other menu item (regardless of what the page might contain), the menu just doesn't appear in my menu.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand Drupal's menu system...it's based entirely on paths and links. So if you want something to appear in the menu, it has to be a link, and it has to have a path. Anything else just doesn't make sense. What you're talking about should be represented using a bunch of different lists of links, each with a heading. It's just a matter of semantics

Comment: It's not that I don't understand that a menu item has to be a link and therefore has to have a path. The reason that I said that it's a problem that a path is required is not that I think it doesn't make sense that a link can be link without a path. It's that I'm trying to figure out something that is workable for the superfish menu to function as desired. Iow, it's not a matter of if links should have paths or not(of course they need to have a path) it's about which paths superfish understands in order to function properly.

Comment: As Superfish is Javascript you might want to implement a javascript solution...one that removes the links from the 'parent' items after the page has loaded...would that do the trick?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do that. I think I'm going to drop this issue. The reason why I'm trying superfish is becuase nicemenu's don't work in firefox in a specific theme. I guess I'm just going to have to figure out how to make nicemenu's work for that theme in firefox after all since superfish is demanding even more patience.

Comment: It would be very easy using JS in case you're still interested: `(function($) { $(function() { $('ul#menu-id > li a').each(function(i, v) { $(this).removeAttr('href'); }); }); })(jQuery);`

Comment: Hey that's very kind of you to suggest. I would love to look into it but haven't touched javascipt for months and never used it in drupal so don't know how to even start and figuring that out is going to take me pretty long I'm sure (I'm extremely slow of comprehension in web dev).

Comment: Yeah I feel your pain, Drupal can be a bit tricky to get the hang of in that respect. Hope you get it sorted anyway

Comment: I noticed in Drupal 6 there is this module called [menu item container](http://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_container). This module does exactly what I'm trying to accomplish but then in Drupal 7. trying to find something similar.  
    ---**EDIT** --->> [This question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7066/drupal-7-menu-item-without-link) here at Drupal Stackexchange handles the same issue I just noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough I've just stumbled across the [Special menu items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module, which is:

> a Drupal module that provides placeholder and separator menu items.
>
> A placeholder is a menu item which is not a link. It is useful with dynamic drop down menus where we want to have a parent menu item which is not linking to a page but just acting as a parent grouping some menu items below it.

I'm pretty sure that's just what you're looking for, and it has a stable release for Drupal 7 :)

Comment: Yes! That's the one. I'm working on it now, should do the job.